# WebKit pyGTK handle custom protocol (apt://)

Tags: webkit, pygtk

I'd like a regular GTK box with a web code. That code will have an install buttons with apt (Firefox is opening that URLs into the Software Center).

```
    self.web = builder.get_object('boxWeb')
    self.web_view = WebKit.WebView()
    self.web_view.open("http://web_with_apt_links")
    self.web_view.show()
    self.web.add(self.web_view)
```

But when I try it, I get an URL error:

```
Unable to load page
Problem occurred while loading the URL apt:package
URL cannot be shown
```

Can I capture the apt links in Linux? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to connect to the `navigation-requested` signal. Here is an example:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, WebKit

class window(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
        webview = WebKit.WebView()
        self.add(webview)
        webview.connect('navigation-requested', self.on_navigation_requested)
        webview.open('http://google.de')
        #webview.open('apt://test')  uncomment to test apt URIs

    def on_navigation_requested(self, view, frame, req):
        uri = req.get_uri()
        if uri and uri.startswith('apt'):
            print('apt uri')
            return WebKit.NavigationResponse.IGNORE
        return WebKit.NavigationResponse.ACCEPT

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win = window()
    win.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Thanks elya5! A complete example even! :)